# What is meant by the term "value" of a scalar quantum field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, terminology, field-theory, cosmological-inflation

During the slow roll of a scalar field, the scalar field is changing its value over time. But what is meant by the term "value" of a scalar field? Since the scalar field is quantized, I don't understand how the field itself can have a value. I read somewhere that it is some sort of average value of the field however that didn't really help me in understanding this.

Comment: I think this would refer  to the *classical* theory. Since the inflaton field is usually assumed to be spatially homogeneous, we can meaningfully talk about its value at a fixed time, in the classical theory.

Comment: @Danu I have no idea about inflation, but  I've heard that some people propose that $\phi$ is actually the Higgs field (i.e., an operator?)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that one can discuss the classical theory. Typically, people first talk about the classical theory, *then* talk about quantization only when they want to talk about fluctuations around the expectation values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is not specific to inflation, and really applies to any case where a bosonic quantum field behaves semiclassically due to macroscopically large occupation numbers. One very simple example of this is the Stark effect in quantum mechanics, where a Hyrodgen atom is placed in a uniform electric field. The atom is treated as a quantum mechanical bound state, but the electric field is treated classically. Of course, both systems are truly quantum, so why is it consistent to treat one quantum mechanically and the other classically?

The reason is that the electric field has a macroscopically large expectation value (in whatever state is being considered), i.e. we may write

$$ A_{\mu} = \langle A_{\mu} \rangle + \delta A_{\mu} $$

where $A_{\mu}$ is the operator-valued gauge field, $\langle A_{\mu} \rangle$ is the expectation value, and $\delta A_{\mu}$ is a fluctuation term with zero mean. In the case where the electric field is very large and may be treated classically, this split makes perturbative sense because $\langle A_{\mu} \rangle^2 >> \langle \delta A_{\mu}^2 \rangle$, and so the fluctuations are small compared to the background value. If you wanted to correct the approach of treating the electric field classically, you could consider fluctuations in $\delta A_{\mu}$ in a perturbative expansion.

This same logic applies to more fancy systems such as Bose-Einstein condensates, which is essentially what the inflaton field is. In this case the bosonic field is a scalar, and once again it has macroscopic occupation numbers so that its fluctuations are suppressed and one may treat the system semi-classically.

Getting back to your specific question about inflation, the value refers to $\langle \phi \rangle$, and this is what is changing over time. You could also ask how the various higher moments of the fluctuations vary over time, i.e. $\langle (\delta \phi)^n \rangle$, for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your atom example, shouldn't the expectation value be taken using the hydrogen atom state instead of the vacuum? As far as I know the VEV of the EM field is zero, and this shouldn't depend on how many photons there are around.

Comment: The formula I wrote is general and applies to any state. If you use the vacuum, then the VEV is zero and all that is present are the fluctuations (in fact, a VEV for the gauge field breaks Lorentz invariance so this had to be the case if we were interested in the vacuum VEV).  In the Hydrogen example, the VEV should be around a state where there is a classical background electric field.

Comment: Awesome. I was just a little confused because you wrote VEV above your equation; technically it's not a *vacuum* expectation value but the expectation value in some state, right? I'm not criticizing, I just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I suppose I should have just written "EV"!

Comment: Unrelated to this discussion, but a question occurred to me: what fixes the scale of this large expectation value? In inflation it is often trans-planckian, even though the background temperature is much lower. Any idea?

Comment: It all depends on the potential and the type of inflation, there's not a model-independent answer to this. But the expectation value and the various parameters in the model should be relatable to various physcial quantities of interest, such as the number of e-folds, the size of the Hubble constant, etc, and these are constrained by observation. Obviously, it would be desirable to have a first principles derivation of these parameters that also happened to match observations.